# Print Number and the Variable before it in Python

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

I have some code that asks for user input then adds it to an array, after the user has entered his/her inputs it then picks the lowest integer and displays it.

```
my_array = []
while numberoftries <= numberofcities:
    print("Please enter city", numberoftries)
    city = input("")
    print("Please enter the temprature for city", numberoftries)
    citytemp = input("")       

    my_array.append(city)
    my_array.append(citytemp)

    print(my_array) # For testing
    print(min(my_array)) # For testing

    numberoftries = numberoftries ++ 1
```

The only problem is I would like to display both the city and the citytemp variables which are both added into the array... I need it to display the lowest integer in the array ie. `print(min(my_array))` and the variable before it, because that variable will be the city name..

Any help or a point in the right direction would be nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you append tuples `my_array.append((citytemp, temp))` instead of `city` and `citytemp` separately. It will work like a charm:

```
>>> min([(2,'toto'), (0,'tutu'), (1,'tata')])
(0, 'tutu')
```

This works because tuples are ordered lexicographically meaning according to first element, so temperature in your case.

You can retrieve the info like so as well:

```
min_temp, min_city = min(my_array)
print min_city, "has lowest temperature:", min_temp
```

Note also that you need to be careful not mixing up integers and strings, `'13'` is not `13` and string comparison can lead to unexpected results:

```
>>>'25'<'Paris'
True

>>>'25'<' Paris '
False
```

Comment: Thank you very much